# ¿Cómo visualizar permisos al usuario?

Tags: android, android-studio

Recién empiezo a crear una APK usando *Android Studio* y me falta visualizar los permisos al usuario, en la APK lo único que me interesa es el *webview* y los permisos. La página que tengo a prueba es para subir archivos/fotos desde la cámara del celular.

Al hacer clic en el botón *examinar* no funciona, pero si funciona desde un computador con Google Chrome. Corríjanme si hago algo mal, gracias

Añado que este código lo encontré y lo agregué porque me da error si no agrego `tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"`

ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     package="com.example.demo3">
 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 <tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
         android:supportsRtl="true"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.Demo3">
         <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>
 
 </manifest>
```

ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">
 
     <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
 
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
 package com.example.demo3;
 
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint; import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
     @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
         WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 
         myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         myWebView.loadUrl("https://nikolodj.webcindario.com/nikolodj/22/");
         //         myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 
 
 
     } }
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el build.gradle para ver como lo tienes configurado en concreto el parametro minSdkVersion. Cuando haces clic a examinar que error te saca el navegador o el logcat?